# filter XY array in C

Tags: c, filtering

See the two screenshots, the data is stored as doubles in a 2D C array.

The first one is my raw data, the second is what I'd like it to be. So I need to remove the points with the red circles. My first try was to compare the y-value of each point with the y value of the previous and next point. If it is lower than both, then remove it.

However, that will also remove the point with the green circle, which should not be removed.

Any suggestions on an algorithm to remove only the points with the red circles? I cannot use a threshold value, since there will also be points like the one with the green circle that are much closer to the x-axis.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: you should explain what the rules are when teh points should be removed and when not

Comment: Are you trying to generate an envelope?

Comment: Isn't this more of a statistical analysis question than a programming question?

Comment: Yes, you could call it an envelope, I hadn't thought about that term yet.

Comment: You may use a low-pass filter.  Seems you have two different tones which have been added together.  By filtering higher spectral component you may get the acquired data set.

Answer (score 2):

How about: Make a pass to find the green dot (the highest dip), then make another pass and remove all dips less than that value?

Comment: The problem I think with that is that there will be more green dots, closer to the x axis (the screenshot is just a narrow example). So cannot just set one to a threshold vale. But maybe I can do that around each maximum, and reset the value of the green dot while moving along the x axis.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? In specific, what are you trying to cull out and what are you trying to keep?

Comment: I'm trying to combine several (gaussian shaped) curves in one plot, and need to remove the points 'under the curve' so they don't show up in the plot. If you carefully look at the first picture, the points with the red circles are actually part of the adjacent curve. The reason I have all these individual curves, is that I start with the coordinates of the maxima, then I calculate each curve, and then I add them all together before plotting. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach.

Instead of filtering all values **after** generating them, I filter them **during** generating the points. So for instance, I calculate the y-value of a specific x-value for the curve it belongs to, but also for its two adjacent curves. Then I check if the point lies under or above one of the adjacent curves, and based on that add them to my curve.

Still tweaking it a bit but it seems much easier and faster to do than do than what I was thinking of initially.